# Multiple hyperlinks from single \includegraphics

Tags: graphics, hyperref, links

I have an image like this which I have included with an `\includegraphics` command.

[image]

I want each of the circles to be a link to a different part of the document.
I.e. clicking on the blue circle should take the user to `\label{blue}`,
clicking on the green circle should take the user to `\label{green}`, etc.

The links may be URLs as well, instead of links to places within the documents. What i'm getting at is something similar to Map/Area in HTML (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_area.asp)

Why? Because the images in question are generated by software, as a result the "maps" can be generated by the software too. Subfigures are not an option since the figures cannot be broken apart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a version with `tikz` nodes overlaying an image and placing `\hyperlinks` with `\nameref{...}` to the sections:

The node positions are up to the user!

[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside]{article}


\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\newcommand{\namereflink}[1]{%
  \nameref{#1}%
% Or use
%  \hyperlink{section.\getrefnumber{#1}}{\nameref*{#1}}%
% Or use
%  \hyperlink{section.\getrefnumber{#1}}{\phantom{}}%  Difficult to detect!!!!
}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
  \hypersetup{hidelinks}
  \node[inner sep=1pt] (MYCENTER) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[scale=1]{ente.jpg}};
  \node (BLUEEDGE) at (-1,1)    {\nameref{sec:blue}}; % For example
  \node (GREENEDGE) at (1,1)    {};
  \node  (REDEDGE) at (-1,-1)   {};
  \node  (ORANGEEDGE) at (1,-1) {};
  \draw[help lines, step=0.25] (MYCENTER) (REDEDGE) grid (GREENEDGE); %Only for help purposes
  \node  (BLUE)   at (-0.5,0.5)  {\namereflink{sec:blue}};
  \node  (GREEN)  at (0.25,0.5)   {\namereflink{sec:green}};
  \node  (RED)    at (-0.25,-0.25) {\namereflink{sec:red}};
  \node  (ORANGE) at (1,-0.25)  {\namereflink{sec:orange}};

  \shade[ball color=blue] (BLUEEDGE) circle (0.5);
  \shade[ball color=green] (GREENEDGE) circle (0.5);
  \shade[ball color=red] (REDEDGE) circle (0.5);
  \shade[ball color=orange] (ORANGEEDGE) circle (0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\clearpage

\section{Blue} \label{sec:blue}

\blindtext[5]


\section{Red} \label{sec:red}

\blindtext[5]

\section{Green} \label{sec:green}

\blindtext[5]

\section{Orange} \label{sec:orange}

\blindtext[5]

And a normal link to \ref{sec:blue}

\end{document}
```

**The code for the real image**

```
\documentclass[oneside]{article}


\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\newcommand{\namereflink}[1]{%
%  \nameref{#1}%
% Or use
%  \hyperlink{section.\getrefnumber{#1}}{\nameref*{#1}}%
% Or use
  \hyperlink{section.\getrefnumber{#1}}{\phantom{#1}}%  Difficult to detect!!!!
}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
  \hypersetup{hidelinks}
  \node  (MYCENTER) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[scale=1]{sourceimage.jpg}};
  \node  (BLUE)   at (-1,1)  {\namereflink{sec:blue}};
  \node  (GREEN)  at (1,1)   {\namereflink{sec:green}};
  \node  (RED)    at (-1,-1)  {\namereflink{sec:red}};
  \node  (ORANGE) at (1,-1)  {\namereflink{sec:orange}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}

\clearpage

\section{Blue} \label{sec:blue}

\blindtext[5]


\section{Red} \label{sec:red}

\blindtext[5]

\section{Green} \label{sec:green}

\blindtext[5]

\section{Orange} \label{sec:orange}

\blindtext[5]

And a normal link to \ref{sec:blue}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome. Really well make example too!

Comment: @kabZX: You're welcome. But perhaps you should generate the image with TikZ etc, not using an `\includegraphics` way.