# Insert chapter Number inside a symbol and a block of text too

Tags: memoir, chapters

The author of a book I am editing would like to insert a certain symbol inside the Chapter Numbers of his book. He wants this:

[image]

Is there a way to insert a symbol in background and be able to write over it?

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[14pt,twoside,showtrims,a5paper,extrafontsizes]{memoir} %Classe estilo memoir
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel} %Traduz doc para português do Brasil
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Reconhece acentuação
\usepackage{lipsum}

\chapterstyle{thatcher}

\begin{document} 
    \renewcommand{\chaptername}{} %remove a string "Capítulo"

    \chapter{Dedicatória}
    \lipsum [2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I thought of hacking it by editing the page in photoshop and including it afterwards, but then I would have lost the TOC reference due to the Chapter page not being counted normally.

Comment: It's possible, for example, using `TikZ` nodes, but does it really look nice? Here's an answer of mine (using hyperlinks, but that can be dropped of course): http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305747/multiple-hyperlinks-from-single-includegraphics

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your use of

```
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}% Remove a string "Chapter"
```

for this chapter is incorrect, as there is still a space remaining as part of the chapter name printing macro. Instead you're looking to redefine `\printchaptername` to something like

```
\renewcommand{\printchaptername}{\centering{\chapnumfont\thechapter}}
```

Now, for setting the number inside some other construction, you can redefine `\printchaptername` to suit your needs. Here is one example using [`pgfornament`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfornament):

[image]

```
\documentclass[14pt,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum,pgfornament}

\chapterstyle{thatcher}

\renewcommand{\printchaptername}{%
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={inner sep=0pt}]
    \node[anchor=south] (image) {\pgfornament[symmetry=h,scale=4]{172}};
    \node at (image.center) {\chapnumfont\thechapter};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Dedicaion}
\lipsum [2]

\end{document}
```

For some ornaments, see

- [Free ornaments font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10941/5764)
- [How do you use `psvectorian`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/175769/5764)

Comment: Thanks for the help @Werner!
I had noticed that the numbers were not really aligned properly, but now they are fine.

Comment: do you think it is possible to draw that symbol I used in the picture with the `Inskape` package as suggested in the `pgfornament` documentation?
Or we rather just change our mind and use some preset symbols.

Comment: @Adriano: Of course! You can overlay or inset objects on top of one another using a number of ways.

Comment: Alright, I will make sure to look for a way of doing it.