# How to use this symbol behind chapter number

Tags: memoir

I have this answer... [Insert chapter Number inside a symbol and a block of text too](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/311130/insert-chapter-number-inside-a-symbol-and-a-block-of-text-too)

And it successfully includes a symbol behind every chapter number. However, I wish I could include this symbol... with the chapter number centered inside the circle...[image]

Or at least just the circle... [image]

Is there a way to substitute the standard symbol?

This is the MWE provided in the answer of the post mentioned before:

```
\documentclass[14pt,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum,pgfornament}

\chapterstyle{thatcher}

\renewcommand{\printchaptername}{%
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={inner sep=0pt}]
    \node[anchor=south] (image) {\pgfornament[symmetry=h,scale=4]{172}};
    \node at (image.center) {\chapnumfont\thechapter};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Dedicaion}
\lipsum [2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the second symbol is easy. Instead of `pgfornament` include it with  `\includegraphics` command: (I've downloaded `.png` and called it `mysymbol`)

```
\documentclass[14pt,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum,tikz}

\chapterstyle{thatcher}

\renewcommand{\printchaptername}{%
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={inner sep=0pt}]
    \node[anchor=south] (image) {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{mysymbol}};
    \node at (image.center) {\chapnumfont\thechapter};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Dedication}
\lipsum [2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

A similar solution works for the first sysmbol, but as you cannot use `image.center`, you'll need some tests to find the correct position:

[image]

```
\documentclass[14pt,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum,tikz}

\chapterstyle{thatcher}

\renewcommand{\printchaptername}{%
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={inner sep=0pt}]
    \node[anchor=south] (image) {\includegraphics[width=3cm]{mysymbol2}};
    \node at ([yshift=9mm]image.south) {\chapnumfont\thechapter};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Dedication}
\lipsum [2]

\end{document}
```