# Text inside picture using memoir

Tags: memoir

I need this picture with some text inside it...

[image]

Is there a way to put the text inside the picture? Make it transparent...write over it...

Comment: I suggest `tikz` nodes. I've done this here, for example, the `hyperref` stuff therein can be omitted, of course: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305747/multiple-hyperlinks-from-single-includegraphics

Comment: I believe that it is a common request and probably simple to do it.
Ok @ChristianHupfer

Comment: Related: [Insert chapter Number inside a symbol and a block of text too](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/311130/5764)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just used the image provided by the O.P. and placed it in a node, then added another node that shows the text.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
  \node[inner sep=1pt] (MYCENTER) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[scale=1]{adriano.png}};
  \node[inner sep=1pt] (foo) at (0.0,1) { \Huge $E = mc^2$ };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update**

```
\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}


\newcommand{\mycenteredtext}{%
\parbox{9cm}{\centering 

Three Rings for the Elven-kings under the sky,

Seven for the Dwarf-lords in their halls of stone,

Nine for Mortal Men doomed to die,

One for the Dark Lord on his dark throne

In the Land of Mordor where the Shadows lie.

One Ring to rule them all, One Ring to find them,

One Ring to bring them all and in the darkness bind them

In the Land of Mordor where the Shadows lie.
}%
}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[step=0.5,very thin,gray] (-6,-6) grid (6,6);
  \node[inner sep=1pt] (MYCENTER) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[scale=1]{adriano1.png}};
  \node[blue] (foo) at (0.0,0.0) { \mycenteredtext  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I believe my text is too big and the image is supposed to center at the middle of the text....
[http://i.imgur.com/QNUjyyQ.jpg]

Comment: @Adriano: yes, but you did neither provide the text nor the real image

Comment: Oh my!
[http://i.imgur.com/KrhihBB.png]
The text is this long:`\textit{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog, the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog, the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog this is it.}`
  
 `\textit{Adriano Fernandes}`

Comment: @Adriano: Thanks for the image: I've updated

Comment: Thanks very much @Christian Hupfer.
I have removed the grid and adjusted the parbox width and the scale.
Done!

Comment: @Adriano: The grid was just for your assistance. I left it on purpose of course to help you